# Ways to stop your Beach blanket from blowing away

Tags: air, summer

When you go to the Beach and lie down your blanket, sometimes they try to blow away if the wind allows. What are some ways of making the blanket stay down as simply sitting stuff on the corner of the blanket does not always work and they are not protected from sand.

*Note: I know you can use pins to hold the blanket in place, but doing this may damage the blanket and may not work in all settings, such as sand and other loose ground particles*.

Comment: I would use a heavier blanket that can't blow away. Not really a "life hack" though, hence the comment.

Answer (score 6):

***Some ways you could do this is:***

[Picture Link](http://lifehacker.com/use-a-fitted-sheet-to-make-a-sand-free-blanket-at-the-b-1560692767)

[image]

- Use a fitted sheet instead of a blanket, this way you can sit stuff in the corners and they there snuggly, plus they are protected from the sand. Sand will stick to a wet cooler, but not with this method.

[From Here:](http://www.diyncrafts.com/7569/lifehacks/20-genius-summer-lifehacks-will-blow-mind/2)

> Just turn up the corners a bit and you can keep your cooler and other
>   items safely away from all of that sand. You can also lay out without
>   worries of sand being all over you when you head home. Plus, sheets
>   are a bit larger than most beach towels so you’ll have loads of room
>   for picnicking or generally enjoying the fun and sun.

Other Methods are:

- Waterproof Yoga mats. As these are easier to clean, also it is so small that you body will keep it from blowing away. But this method is not the best.

Answer (score 2):

I used to bury the edges of the towel in the sand so the wind can't get under it any more. On a windy day, add more sand.
It's impossible not to get sand everywhere anyway, so there's no point in trying to keep the towel clean.

Answer (score 1):

Where I come from, you can get small weights with a small alligator clip attached, they are used for tying down tablecloths when eating outside.
Typically they're made of plastic,  shaped like a small animal and has steel balls or lead shot inside

These weights also work on whatever type of sheet you bring to the beach.

A "lifehacked" version would be a small cloth bag filled with anything heavy (stones, lead shot, sand, etc.) , a string attached to it, and an alligator clip at the end of the string.

Instead of an alligator clip, you can tie the baggie to one of these for added durability and practicality:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add loops to the corners of your blanket and then use plastic (foot safe) stakes to hold down each corner. Stakes are less likely to pull free in the wind than just tucking corners into the sand.